# Onload for load

Tags: word-usage

Comments on the use of “onload” for “load” as in “He will onload the truck.” Is it to avoid confusion with “unload the truck”?

It seems “onload” is superfluous. You simply “load the truck”. “Unload” is then preferable to “offload”.

NGram Viewer shows continuous usage of “unload” for the past 200 years. “Onload” only began to be used in the last ten years.

Comment: It's being used as the opposite of "offload".

Comment: I've never hear of 'onload' - Is this a colloquialism? 

'Load up the truck' (or just load) is more commonplace surely? Surely 'onload' sounds so much like 'unload' it should be avoided ?

Comment: [Onload](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onload) is a word, but its definition equates it with *load*. I'm used to hearing *onboard*, but I had to look up *onload* as it was something I hadn't heard before. [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=load+the+truck%2C+unload+the+truck%2C+onload+the+truck&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cload%20the%20truck%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunload%20the%20truck%3B%2Cc0) shows no functional hits for *onload the truck*. What is your actual question?

Comment: Agree with @HotLicks. I could see it being used in contexts where it's important to distinguish. For example, large crude oil tankers that are used for both export and import, sometimes in the vicinity of the same port.